# How to get tags only with custom meta field and display them randomly?

Tags: terms, tags

I'm trying to have a function to display only the tags with custom meta field `tax_image_url_universal` and display them randomly, which means when page reloads different tags to be displayed.

Currently I have the following to display random tags, but I don't know how to restrict them first with the custom meta field.
Thanks for any advice.

```
function wpll_get_popular_nodes() {
    $args = array('exclude' => '36 17'); 
    $alltags = get_tags( $args );
    shuffle($alltags);
    $count=0;
    if($alltags) {
        foreach($alltags as $tag) {
            $count++;
            echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
            if( $count >4 ) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get custom fields randomly using the below code that you can combine with your existing code to get desired output.

```
function wpll_get_popular_nodes() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_fields = $wpdb->get_results( "select DISTINCT meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta pt LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON (pt.post_id = p.ID) where meta_key LIKE 'tax_image_url_universal' ORDER BY RAND()" );
    if ( is_array( $custom_fields ) && ! empty( $custom_fields ) ) {
        $count=0;
        foreach ( $custom_fields as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $field->meta_value ) ) {
                $count++;
                echo $field->meta_value;
            }
            if( $count >4 ) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code but I got no results at all. However I have around 10 tags with 
 'tax_image_url_universal' meta value on my site. Did I miss anything? @Vinod Dalvi

Comment: The 'tax_image_url_universal' should be meta key and not meta value.

Comment: Sorry that was wrong expression, I wanted to say that is the meta key, and they have different urls as their value. However output was empty using your code.